# Erro ao instalar o Laravel via composer (Mcrypt required)

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

Ao tentar instalar o Laravel via composer, ele me disse que precisa da extensão 
Mcrypt.

Estou usando SO linux ubuntu 13.04
Servidor Zend Server CE 6.3
apache 2.2;
php5.4;

Mas nada do danado funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Acabei de fazer no meu Linux 14.04 LTS